# Writing custom rules related to Java variable declaration

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am working on solution for Avoid assigning several variables to the same value in a single statement. any java class containing variable declared like below program should display error. I am going through sonar cube custom rules. Please help me if there is any other way to achieve this

```
String a,b,c="test";
```

Answer (score 2):

[S1659](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS1659) "Multiple variables should not be declared on the same line" should do what you want, although it will raise an issue whether or not a value is assigned at declaration.

Comment: I want to implement the same using custom rule. Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: Why do you want to do the same thing with a custom rule if the standard rule does what you want? Besides, it's a best practice to declare each variable on a separate line. If you follow that rule won't your rule be moot?